# How can I make a wire transfer from Japan?

Tags: japan, money

I'm here in Tokyo for 6 month for an internship and would like to transfer remaining funds from my earning back to the United States while going back.

Unfortunately my Japanese skills are very limited and I do not know a lot of people around Tokyo except company co-workers. I have a bank account in [Mitsubishi UFJ (Bank of Tokyo)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bank_of_Tokyo-Mitsubishi_UFJ,_Ltd.) and I would like to transfer some money via a wire transfer back to the United States in my bank account at Bank of America.

Is there an easy procedure to do this? I have been trying to find on MUFJ websites but since I do not know any Japanese, it has been quite difficult.

Comment: I was in Korea three or four years ago in the same hostel as a guy who was doing a visa run from Japan. At that time there was no way to wire money from Japan! No Moneygram, no Western Union, nothing. I think they ended up either sending cash in regular mail, or getting somebody who was flying to Korea anyway to bring the money with them. I don't know if the situation has improved. I don't know how guest workers do remittances. It could be worth asking on both the [money](http://money.stackexchange.com/) and [expats](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) sites though.

Comment: I do not think that this refers to travel to Japan but rather to issues around foreigners living in Japan. You might want to refer to http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Actually I'm not an expatriate living in Japan. I'm here for a short duration of 6 months on an Internship and would like to transfer the funds I had remaining back home from my earnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, MUFJ, that mutant offspring of semi-insolvent Japanese banks.  You're in for some fun times!

The sanest way to approach this is to go to the bank branch and ask, they'll rustle up somebody with enough English to help you out.  The Japanese keyword is [外国送金](https://faq01.bk.mufg.jp/EokpControl?&tid=1149141&event=FE0006&searchToken=1395742201219) (*gaikokusōkin*).

A few pointers:

- Not all branches handle remittances, so pick a nice big branch that does. See [branch locator](http://sasp.mapion.co.jp/b/bk_mufg/count/?foreign_remittance=%E5%A4%96%E5%9B%BD%E9%80%81%E9%87%91%E5%8F%96%E6%89%B1%E5%BA%97) (Jp only).
- Bring lots of ID, both personal and bank-related.  Make sure you know your "anshin bangō" security code and can sign your signature the way you did when you opened your account.
- Find out everything you possibly can about the bank account you're sending to.  This includes SWIFT codes, branch names, branch addresses, etc.
- Expect it to take forever.  Seriously, if you're out of there in less than an hour, it's a good day.
- Expect to pay [around Y10,000](http://www.bk.mufg.jp/tesuuryou/gaitame.html) for the privilege, more if you're sending lots.

Comment: Ah I see. I checked the links you provided as well and I think this should solve my issue. Now my only issue remains whether I want to pay JPY 10000+ for that transfer. Thanks!